# Fixed no-repeat background image in centered div?

Tags: frontend, page-layout, css

I've got a fixed-width centered div with a fixed no-repeat background image in it, and the background image needs to be off-centered. However, when the window is resized, whether the image is fixed using percentage or pixel coordinates, it does not stay positioned correctly within the div.

Is there a way to either: 
1) fix a background image to its div rather than the page, or
2) use a similar hack to the "left:50%; margin-left:/**$twice-the-pixel-size-of-div-width**/;" div centering hack to get the fixed background image to stay at the same spot in the centered div when the page is resized?

Comment: Could you please give a http://jsfiddle.net example of the problem?

Comment: A jsfiddle.net example is almost necessary for this problem, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Is the background-position property what you're looking for?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp